# Why is my Runescape character/username missing or reset?

Tags: runescape, oldschool-runescape

I've played Runescape since about 2006/2007 but quit right after the citadel update. I have come back after about 5 years because I heard about the Oldschool Runescape fork. I am aware it resets your character for OSRS, but that should not be the case for RS3. I was forced to create a new username and it reset my whole character. I wasn't hacked, it's just that everything is reset. Completely fresh character.

I have checked with all my emails and made sure that there was only one account associated with each email address. There is only one. Just to stress this - I am in complete control of my accounts and always have been, this is not a problem with account security.

I am planning on playing OSRS, but i'll be damned if i'm not getting my character back if i'm able to.

Was there an update that messed with the accounts/usernames/whatever? Is there a way to recover my old username/character?

I'm really not sure what to do next. I can supply any other information if I need to.

Comment: From my experience with MMOs, accounts are usually deleted after 1 year of inactivity. For subscription-based MMOs, it's 1 year after the subscription ended. I highly doubt your account would still be around after 5 years.

Comment: If your character's been reset, it's been reset.  What help are you looking for?  If it's character restoration, there's nothing we can do.

Comment: Frank, I don't even have my old username. It wanted me to make a new username. I want to know if there was some sort of update or anything that happened to the old characters. I wouldn't think that my character is just gone; my record is completely clean of everything, so I don't think it would have gotten deleted. I'm just looking for an answer as to what could have happened, or anything to help if it's a known issue.

Comment: We're not really here to help you with guessing.  If you have a concrete issue, focus on that.  We need something more to go on than what you currently have, as you're all over the place.  Do you want to know if usernames get deleted after a period of inactivity?  Do you want help restoring your old account?  Be specific.  The clearer you are, the better the chance we can help, or at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/15iPD0hA - Pastebin because it's slightly too long.

Comment: @Nolonar RuneScape does not delete accounts. I had an old account that I hadn't played in nearly ten years, and which had never been subscribed, and it was just how I left it.

Comment: The same thing happend to me.

Answer (score 9):

Everybody in old school runescape starts from scratch, your old stats and account should still be around in runescape 3 but you cannot transfer this to old school.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Everyone started from scratch again in OSRS.

Comment: I believe you should still have your friends list though.  Many of the usernames may have changed or been deleted, but you should have the same number as your RS3 account does.

Answer (score 6):

Jagex will [free up your username](https://runescape.wiki/w/Character_name#Inactive_users) if you haven't logged in for a while, but I don't think I've ever heard of an account being completely wiped like that.

Sometimes stats will be reset because of botting or bug abuse, but not completely reset like this. My hunch is that you're probably mistaken about logging in with the correct email. That's been the case for [other people](http://runescape.salmoneus.net/forums/topic/362661-has-my-character-been-deleted/#entry4133459) that have the same issue.

Comment: From the question it looks like the OP is confused.
RS and OSRS are separate games, thus starting from fresh.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm some of the answers given. Just returned to my Runescape account and for RS3 my my skills feel slightly off but not completely reset. My armor and sword were in inventory because I was not at 50 attack for the blue scimitar and the green armor I think its 40 I needed to wear it. So skills seem to deteriorate or something. This is not so bad though as I'm only about 10 pts under. A grind yes, could be frustrating for 99 players down to say 89 but other than that not so crazy.

The worst part is the name did change. I was Krilon1 now I'm OPBR864 which is unbelievably generic. I noticed I need to be member to change the name. Name changing to free up after years of not playing is understandable. But what isn't is the ability to change the name requires membership sub. Hopefully, we can do some sort of ticket to get a free name change based on the fact of a generic name given to us after a long term leave of absence. Otherwise, it would be a bit of a shrewd business.

I cannot say anything about OSRS at this time. I suspect that because its technically an entity of its own that your account was updated through the main hub of runescape classic, runescape 2, and runescape 3 that you would need to make a new character for OSRS. Which is cool because when OSRS first came out it probabaly was entirely made of new characters newbs grinding out the game all over again. So nothing to fret about there. I might even do that myself.

Comment: Skills do not deteriorate, but they changed the level requirements slightly.

Comment: You can buy membership bonds for in-game gold, though they can be expensive.  It is an option if you really want to change your name but don't want to pay for a month of membership to do so

Answer (score 1):

After a period of inactivity Jagex takes character names and releases them back into the pool for other people to use for new RS3 accounts hence the lack of a character name for you. As for the stats and reset with the EoC update all skills were tweaked slightly resulting in some skill levels being lowered as their maximums had been increased or level differences being modified. I don't see why your whole character would have been wiped though as I recently recovered an account of mine that I started in 2006 and havent played on since 07 and i had only lost about 1-2 levels on all F2P skills.

I would say contact Jagex about it. Give your old Display name, the email address associated with it and all the other information you can and in the notes at the bottom explain what has happened. They will probably tell you that the account is still there just not where you thought it was.

OSRS is completely seperate to RS3 just to add. If you want to play OSRS you start from scratch regardless if you had an account from 06/07 those accounts became RS3 accounts only.

And dont worry about starting again in OSRS I wasnt completely sold on it myself but I jumped in and I love it so much more than RS3. the EoC ruined Runescape for me completely so OSRS is a god send. You'll fall in love with it again if you enjoyed it back in the day.